# QT: only one widget response the key press event when there is two widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, qkeyevent

I have two widgets in my application, and I want to do something in the widget when the key is pressed. However, I find only one widget response the key press event even the other one has the focus.

The code to reproduce my problem is:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys, os

class Widget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.grabKeyboard()
        self.name=name

    def keyPressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().keyPressEvent(*args, **kwargs)
        print('key press: ', self.name)

    def focusInEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().focusInEvent(*args, **kwargs)
        print('focus in: ', self.name)

class MyWin(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(100, 100)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.w1 = Widget('w1')
        self.w1.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)')
        layout.addWidget(self.w1)

        self.w2 = Widget('w2')
        self.w2.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)')
        layout.addWidget(self.w2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWin()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When I press the key board, only `w2` response the key press event. How to let both two widgets response the key press event?

Enviornment is:

```
win10
python 3.7
pyqt 5.15.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [widget.grabKeyboard()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabKeyboard) as this will force all keyboard input to be re-directed to the last widget which called the method.